# Matrices and System of linear equations check?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

I completed this problem myself and was wondering if someone could check if it is correct or not. This is a homework problem and am not asking for people to complete it for me but just to tell me if it is right or wrong.

The following shipping log excerpt from a technology warehouse displays the number of each of four brands of laptops (A, B, C, D) ordered by each of three retailers, along with the total bill for each shipment.

```
  Laptop| Wal-Mart | Target | Best Buy
    A   |     5    |    7   |    4
    B   |     6    |    8   |    4
    C   |     0    |    3   |    6
    D   |     8    |    0   |    4
Total($)|   13600  |  12000 |  11400
```

Let a,b,c and d denote the wholesale price, respectively, of laptop brands A, B, C, and D.

- Write a system of linear equations in a,b,c, and d that represents the given information
- Rewrite the above system of equations as a vector equation
- Rewrite the above system of equations as a matrix equation
- Rewrite the above system of equations as an augmented matrix
- Use row reduction to solve the above system of equations. Write your answer in parametric vector form
- Suppose it is also known that the wholesale price of laptop C is $500. Determine the wholesale prices of laptops A,B, and D.

What I got:

```
5a+6b+0c+8d = 13600
7a+8b+3c+0d = 12000
4a+4b+6c+4d = 11400
```

Vector form:

```
 [5]    [6]     [0]     [8]   [13600]
a[7] + b[8]  + c[3]  + d[0]  =[12000]
 [4]    [4]     [6]     [4]   [11400]
```

Matrix form:

```
[5 6 0 8]
[7 8 3 0]
[4 4 6 4]
```

Augmented matrix:

```
[5 6 0 8 | 13600]
[7 8 3 0 | 12000] 
[4 4 6 4 | 11400]
```

RREF:

```
[1 0 9 0 | 4960]
[0 1 -15/2 0 | -2840] 
[0 0 0 1 | 730]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is "check my work please".

Comment: Is that not allowed?

Comment: Pure check my work are not encouraged especially if it is related to homework. Also it is much more valuable if you learn to check your own work.

Comment: not sure how to check if its right without asking

Comment: Dan, There is a tag "solution verification" which is a synonym of "proof verification.  There is nothing wrong about asking this question; there are many such questions; and I and others encourage as much work from the asker as possible, and you've done just that.

Comment: @mathreadler Could you cite the source from which you assert such an misinformed opinion?

Comment: @amWhy: I derive it from the responses I have read to other similar questions I have seen on the site.

Comment: It may be helpful to say where the numbers 13600, 12000, and 11400 come from. Currently they appear out of nowhere as the right hand side in an equation. Presumably, they represent the total money spent for each company, but this is not specified in the question.

Comment: @NickAlger sorry those are the totals

Comment: You can check your work by finishing the last step (finding the values a,b,c,d), then plugging the answers you get into the original system, and seeing if each side of the resulting equations are indeed equal. Another way to check your work is to solve the system by computer (with, say, octave, https://octave-online.net/), then check that you get the same answer.